# How to properly set min_itemsize in HDFStore.append?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have read following Q&As:

[How to specify min_itemsize for an index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222271/how-to-specify-min-itemsize-for-an-index-column)

[Pandas pytable: how to specify min_itemsize of the elements of a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710738/pandas-pytable-how-to-specify-min-itemsize-of-the-elements-of-a-multiindex)

but still cannot make my toy example work:

```
with pd.HDFStore('teststore.h5') as store:
    chunk = pd.DataFrame({"V1":["a","b","c","d","e"], "data":np.arange(5)}).set_index(["V1"])
    store.append("gr1", chunk, min_itemsize={chunk.index.name: 32 })

    chunk = pd.DataFrame({"V1":["aaaah!!!"], "data": 3}).set_index(["V1"])
    store.append("gr1", chunk, min_itemsize={chunk.index.name: 32 })
```

returns: `ValueError: min_itemsize has the key [V1] which is not an axis or data_column`, while:

```
with pd.HDFStore('teststore.h5') as store:
    chunk = pd.DataFrame({"V1":["a","b","c","d","e"], "data":np.arange(5)}).set_index(["V1"])
    store.append("gr1", chunk, min_itemsize={"index": 32 })

    chunk = pd.DataFrame({"V1":["aaaah!!!"], "data": 3}).set_index(["V1"])
    store.append("gr1",chunk, min_itemsize={"index": 32 })
```

returns:

```
ValueError: Trying to store a string with len [8] in [index] column but
this column has a limit of [1]!
Consider using min_itemsize to preset the sizes on these columns
```

What is a correct / working way?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: the latest. The issue has been submitted to Github. It is a bug